# How to change EncryptionMethod Algorithm to xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p in WebSphere ND 8.5.5

Tags: websphere, jax-ws, ws-security

I am running a JAX-WS web service client on an IBM WebSphere 8.5.5.10 traditional server. The WSDL requires encryption and signing. I am configuring the WS-Security in an Application Policy set and General Client policy set and attaching those to the application.

The service provider expects EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"

WebSphere is sending

Can someone tell me how to change the EncryptionMethod Algorithm to xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p in the Policy set?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this from IBM. It answered my question.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/uwbs_wsspsal.html

To view this administrative console page: 
1.  Click Services > Policy sets > Application policy sets > policy_set_name.
2.  Click the WS-Security policy in the Policies table.
3.  Click the Main policy link or the Bootstrap policy link.
4.  Click the Algorithms for symmetric tokens link or the Algorithms for asymmetric tokens link.
This administrative console page applies only to Java API for XML Web Services (JAX-WS) applications.

Comment: If you changed an existing policy, its a good idea to restart the app server before attempting to use it again.  Alternatively, you can refresh the policy manager using this jacl script in wsadmin: set psm [$AdminControl queryNames type=PolicySetManager,*]
$AdminControl invoke $psm refresh  (sorry, I can't format that well in a comment).  You'd just have to restart your app if you do that.